# I have Horizontal scroll bar in my website page

Tags: html, css

I am building this website using a theme. Now i see there is a horizontal scroll bar in bottom of my website, when tried to scroll I see white spaces. Tried adding width: 100%; and min-width: 940px; to body still didn't work.

Could anybody please help me resolve this?

Here is the website.

http://alkurbi.com/beta/

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: post your code please

Comment: Use the dev tools to try and find which element is breaking out of the flow. Your 'client's slider is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try do this

```
.vc_row.wpb_row.vc_row-fluid.vc_custom_1448640443943.ult-vc-hide-row,
 .vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid {
   max-width:100% !important;
       }
```

also you have to use container for section : CHAIRMAN MESSAGE

also you may add :

```
body {
 overflow-x:hidden;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this css in your body :

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```